# error: migrate sqlite3 db to postgresql for rails app hosted on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sqlite3-ruby

I am trying to host my rails app on heroku, i set the app up initially usually sqlite3 because i didn't realise it wasn't compatible with Heroku. I'm trying to follow railscast #342 but I keep getting errors and not sure how to fix them. When i run the command

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

I get a sequence of errors:

```
FATAL:  role "jen" does not exist
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:665:in `rescue in connect'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:655:in `connect'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:93:in `create'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:107:in `block in create_current'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:275:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each_current_configuration'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:106:in `create_current'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/jen/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'

Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"myapp_development", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"jen", "password"=>nil}
```

Can anyone shed any light as to what is causing these errors? I have tried

```
sudo su - postgres
```

but it's asking me for a password that I don't know.

UPDATE:

this is my database.yml file:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
# default: &default
#   adapter: sqlite3
#   pool: 5
#   timeout: 5000

# development:
#   <<: *default
#   database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
# test:
#   <<: *default
#   database: db/test.sqlite3

# production:
#   <<: *default
#   database: db/production.sqlite3

development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: mygaisce_development
  pool: 5
  username: jen
  password: secret

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: mygaisce_test
  pool: 5
  username: jen
  password: secret
```

Comment: you most probably need to create a jen user in postgres.  try `sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser jen` then `sudo -u postgres psql` then `\password jen`

Comment: thanks, but then i get the error `sudo: unknown user: postgres`

Comment: how did you install postgres?

Comment: on my laptop, i had previously installed it for a different project. is that what you mean? For the project, I used `gem install pg` . I updated the post above to include my database.yml file. I'm not sure if that could be the source of the error

Comment: use the same database config you used in the other project.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have data about db in production.
Try to add

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
```

in `database.yml`